# Getting null pointer exception in selenium when reading form Excel File, unable to find work around

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I am new to selenium and I have written a Keyword driven framework which reads from an excel file and according to the value present, it performs operation.
So while reading file, in a particular row, if first cell contains value, it is a Test case Name else it a keyword.

Now when it reads first cell without any value, it throws java.lang.NullPointerException for that line.

Below is the part of my Code:

```
   Sheet sheet = file.ReadExcelFile("E:\\workspace\\Practice1", "Keywords.xlsx", "Sheet1");
    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();
     for (int i = 1; i < rowCount+1; i++) {    
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        //Below line gives me null pointer error
        if(row.getCell(0).toString().length()==0){  
            System.out.println(row.getCell(1).toString()+"----"+ row.getCell(2).toString()+"----"+
            row.getCell(3).toString()+"----"+ row.getCell(4).toString());
        //Call perform function to perform operation on UI
            operation.perform(allObjects, row.getCell(1).toString(), row.getCell(2).toString(),
                row.getCell(3).toString(), row.getCell(4).toString());
     }
        else{
            //Print the new testcase name when it started
                System.out.println("New Testcase->"+row.getCell(0).toString() +" Started");
            }
    }
```

I tried to resolve using ternary(?) operator as below:
if(row.getCell(0)==null?"":row.getCell(0))

but getting error for it as cannot convert from object to boolean; tried typecating it to boolean but that didn't work also.

Is there any other way or better way to write it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are proposing replacing the line

```
if(row.getCell(0).toString().length()==0){
```

with the line

```
if(row.getCell(0)==null?"":row.getCell(0)) {
```

but this won't work, because the expression `row.getCell(0)==null?"":row.getCell(0)` doesn't have a `boolean` value.  It has either the value `""`, a `String`, or `row.getCell(0)`, which I assume returns `Object`.

It seems you want the contents of the `if` block to run if `row.getCell(0)` is an empty string or `null`.  If this is the case, then the simplest thing to do is to write

```
if(row.getCell(0) == null || row.getCell(0).toString().length()==0){
```

Comment: Tried with row.getCell(0) == null too but still getting null pointer exception. Any other workaround or solution?

Comment: @AakashGoyal: in that case you'll have to debug and find out exactly what is null.  If you're getting a NullPointerException, some value is null and you've attempted to use it without checking that it was null.  This question has nothing to do with Selenium, it's just basic Java debugging.  I don't have your code nor your spreadsheet so I'm afraid I can't help you any more than that.

Comment: @Akash, inspect the row object during first iteration while debugging, it might give you clue why are you getting null piinter exception. As Luke  Woodward suggest, you have to debug the code. It has nothing to do with selenium.